# Is this a subject-verb disagreement?

Tags: verb-agreement

This is the commonly used verbatim license (https://www.gnu.org/licenses/licenses.html#VerbatimCopying):

> Verbatim copying and distribution of this entire article are permitted worldwide, without royalty, in any medium, provided this notice is preserved.

Shouldn't the word "is" be there instead of "are"?

I'm pretty sure yes, just asking because this license is used *everywhere* and it would be surprising if everybody made the same mistake.

Comment: Related: [Agreement With Compound Subjects Joined by And](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117346)

Comment: 'Both running and walking are permitted in the park'. It would not read 'both running and walking _is_ permitted in the park'.

Comment: It's easier to see the subject is plural if the sentence is rephrased as, "This entire article's verbatim copying and distribution are permitted worldwide, without royalty, in any medium, provided this notice is preserved." Admittedly it sounds awkward and nobody would say it that way, but grammatically it means exactly the same thing.

Comment: I'd argue that either is possible here, but 'are' focuses on A or B (as well as both) being permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying and distribution are two different things, so this is a compound subject joined by the conjunctive coordinating conjunction. It is therefore a plural subject, demanding a plural verb.

Look at it this way:

> - Copying is permitted.
>
> *plus*
>
> - Distribution is permitted.
>
> *equals*
>
> - Copying and distribution are both permitted.