# Usage of was with two subjects grouped

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

When is it appropriate to use "was" (or the singular form of a verb) when two subjects are grouped? Would the usage of the singular imply the subject is "the relationship of those two subjects"

E.g. Key and Peele was/were funny. (An established group)

E.g. Jim and Pam was/were the best part of *The Office*. (a specific pairing often used together)

E.g. Chewbecca and the Porgs was/were entertaining in *The Last Jedi*. (In this case does was have a different meaning than were?)

E.g. Jack and Jill was/were running.

My "intuition" is that was is appropriate in the first three cases, while it's obviously not appropriate in the last one, but I can't determine why it would be appropriate in the middle two.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Agreement With Compound Subjects Joined by And](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117346/agreement-with-compound-subjects-joined-by-and)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your example sentences should use *was*.

The only time when the singular should be used with an *X and Y* subject is when the subject is a collective singular rather than the conjunction of two separate subjects.

For example:

> The fish and chips I ate was good.
>   *Porgy and Bess* was written by George Gershwin.
>   *Key & Peele* was a comedy television series.
>   *Penn & Teller* is a comedy act.

But:

> The fish and side of chips I ate were good.
>   Porgy and Bess were opposed by Crown and Sportin' Life.
>   Key and Peele were stars of a TV show.
>   Penn and Teller are comedians.

However, you can also change the subject in the sentence from two conjoined plurals to a singular:

> Chewbacca and the Porgs *were* entertaining.
>   The interaction of Chewbacca and the Porgs *was* entertaining.