# Should I use "is" or "are" between two nouns (I think) in this phrase?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I'm not really sure what I should use in this case, normally I can identify the difference but this time for some reason i cannot.

sentence: "In this function stringify and parse is necessary"

Is necessary
or
Are necessary

Comment: (2) Is 'stringify and parse' regarded  as two separate entities (John and Lucy; an apple and an orange) or a composite (rhythm and blues; fish and chips)? And (1) are you a synesis believer? I suppose (0) what POSs should we ascribe to 'stringify' and  'parse' (or the compound 'stringify and parse'?) here? and (0') Is the string acceptable? are also necessary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think they should be separate entities. I don't really know what synesis means. And I need to use 'stringify' because its basically a function I need to call in a programming language and stringify is it's name.

Comment: You seem to be using 'stringify' and 'parse' (or 'stringify and parse') as labels. This converts them to nouns, as in 'A and * are not working' or 'Fish and chips is on the menu'. This question is then a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Agreement With Compound Subjects Joined by And](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117346/agreement-with-compound-subjects-joined-by-and)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a singular operation (`stringify and parse`), then you would use "is".

> In this function, `stringify and parse` is necessary.

If you are talking about two operations (`stringify` and `parse`), then you would use "are".

> In this function, `stringify` and `parse` are necessary.

It is likely that you mean the second.