# The reason for A and B are/is C and D

Tags: punctuation

The reason for A and B *are/is* C and D. Should it be "is" or "are"?

How about in this context:

> The principal philosophical motivation and practical result of the constriction of economic freedom in Atlas Shrugged is the redistribution of wealth and the asphyxiation of industrialists.

Comment: Ask yourself this: Is *reason* singular or plural?

Comment: Ask yourself, are C and D reasons or a reason? Many C and D are fixed collocations that can well go as singular. This and more depends on context.

Comment: I've used up my daily review votes so I can't VTC as a duplicate, but I think this is a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117346/agreement-with-compound-subjects-joined-by-and/117351#117351

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Agreement With Compound Subjects Joined by And](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117346/agreement-with-compound-subjects-joined-by-and)