# Compound subject with "is" or "are"

Tags: word-choice, compound-subjects

I'm proofreading a text that includes the following passage:

> Semiology is defined in *A Glossary of Literary Terms* as ‘the
> systematic study of signs, as these function in all areas of human
> existence’. So perhaps this is what all modern literary and artistic study is.

It's the second sentence I'm having trouble with, particularly the phrase, "what all modern literary and artistic study ***is***."

I can't decide whether that sentence should end with "is" or "are". If I were editing, I would just rewrite the sentence, but I don't have the remit to do that as a proofreader.

A compound subject linked with the word "and" would normally take the plural:

"…what all modern literary [study] and artistic study are."

But neither "is" nor "are" sound correct to me.

I'm assuming that it is a compound subject in that it is referring to two types of study (literary study and artistic study) rather than a single subject (study that is, at the same time, both artistic and literary).

Is this a compound subject, as I'm assuming it to be, or a single subject? Or is there a better way to think about this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Agreement With Compound Subjects Joined by And](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117346/agreement-with-compound-subjects-joined-by-and) (1) Forget the terminology, and the actual example you have, which is complicated by the 'this is'. The duplicate looks at whether the 'twinned' (coordinate) subject is really two items, or really a single cohesive whole (eg 'Bacon and eggs is not on the menu'). Here (though not necessarily in all examples using the twinned phrase), I'd consider 'all ...

Comment: modern literary and artistic study' to be a largely cohesive discipline, and use singular agreement. (2) Happily, this does not jar when preceded by the 'this is' (though the style, 'this is all X is', seems to border on the informal).

Comment: There isn't a compound subject joined by "and" here. The subject is "all study", which is qualified by "modern" and "literary and artistic". What's joined by "and" is the adjectival phrase. So the overall noun phrase clearly calls for singular agreement.

Comment: Thanks Karl, that makes sense. PS I'm new to stack exchange, so I'm not sure how to upvote your answer when it has been given in a comment.

Comment: What @KarlKnechtel said. The one and only subject noun is ***study***, which is obviously singular.

Comment: The analysis is not as simple as others have suggested; 'Association and rugby football are different sports' shows that a deletion of the noun in the first NP is possible. But if you _do_ wish to indicate '[modern] literary study' and ' ... artistic study' as being distinct fields, it would be better, as you suggest, to include both instances of 'study'.

Comment: The head of the NP is the singular noun "study", which means that the verb should also be singular, i.e. "is". The other dependents, "modern literary and artistic" are modifiers within the nominal of which "study" is head.

Comment: The subject is "all modern literary and artistic study", in which "all" is determiner, "study" is head, and the remainder are modifiers.

Comment: Would there be so much fuss about an irrelevant detail like singular/plural _be_ agreement if the sentence had been _So perhaps this is  modern literary and artistic study_, I wonder. I doubt it seriously. And yet simply forming a _Wh_-cleft out of that sentence left the _is_ protruding from the sentence, where it is prone to damage.

Comment: I don't see it as a cleft, but a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) meaning "So perhaps this is the answer to the question 'What is all modern literary and artistic study?'"

Answer (score 0):

Using "is" works fine when you understand the author to mean that modern (literary and artistic) study refers to a single type of study.  The **and** is joining two adjectives, not two nouns.

Comment: But in 'Many fires and stoves use a combination of radiant and convected heat', one must realise the deletion of the first noun, thus:  'Many fires and stoves use a combination of radiant heat and convected heat'. And this string would not use singular agreement: '_Radiant and convected heat_ **are** quite different forms of heat transfer.' The and **may be** (and in the 'heat' example **is**) joining two NPs, not adjectives. The old 'and' ambiguity needs addressing: 'Jane likes red and white cars.'

Comment: @perpetual Your are right.The head of the NP is the singular noun "study", which means that the verb should also be singular, i.e. "is". The other dependents, "modern literary and artistic" are modifiers within the nominal of which "study" is head. The fact that the dependents may form a coordination is not relevant here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth is right that "modern literary and artistic study" could mean "modern literary study AND modern artistic study." As I reflect on this, I wonder if it's the word "all" that is significant: "Literary study and artistic study are important." but "All literary study and artistic study is important." If this is correct, then I think KarlKnechtel was closest to the right answer when he said that the subject of this sentence is "all study" and therefore should use the singular "is."

Comment: @MatthewParkinson Not quite: "all" is a determiner in the subject NP "**all modern literary and artistic study**". Singular "study" is head and the rest are modifiers.

Comment: @BillJ but do you agree that one would say "literary study and artistic study ARE important" and "ALL literary study and artistic study IS important"?