# "has been" vs "have been" when dealing with multiple nouns

Tags: verbs, nouns, have

I have seen a lot of similar questions asked but none of them applies to my case. If it exists, please do post the link.

So, my question is do we use have or has been when referring to more than one noun? Both seem right to me.

Example:

Their support and expertise **have** or **has** been crucial for this project's completion.

Comment: It depends. _Both are correct in their own way_ is the short answer to this oft-asked question on this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Agreement With Compound Subjects Joined by And](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117346/agreement-with-compound-subjects-joined-by-and) The answer key: (1) Do you favour synesis ('notional agreement')? (a) If not, 'A & B are / have been ...' is all you are left with. This can get tricky! (b) If so, is 'support and expertise' **_as used here**_ logically considered a composite (compare the somewhat easier 'bacon and eggs is my favourite breakfast' and 'health and safety is our primary concern'). If so, singular verb form. If not, plural verb form.