# Appropriate management and supervision of tourism centers "is" or "are" essential?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions, compound-subjects

Which one is correct and why?

1. Appropriate management and supervision of tourism centers *is* essential.
2. Appropriate management and supervision of tourism centers *are* essential.

Comment: what research have you done? Do you have any suggestions about which is correct and why?

Comment: possibly of interest: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39838/is-group-singular-or-plural

Comment: Also see [Singular verb after two noun phrases joined by “and” that can be thought of as a single thing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97459)