# Time and tide waits or wait?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

In my grammar book, in a chapter on subject-verb agreement, the author said that when two nouns, joined by *and*, are suggesting the same idea or person, we consider the nouns as one unit and use a singular verb, e.g. in 
*The novelist and poet is dead*.

Among many examples he gave, I caught attention of this one:

> Time and tide **waits** for none.

This didn't appear correct to me. I think it should have been:

> Time and tide **wait** for none.

I went on to look on the internet and found conflicting resolutions to this. Different references said differently. What do you think is correct? And what's the reason behind your answer?

#### EDIT

A possible duplicate has been raised for my question: [Time and tide wait for no man](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95513/time-and-tide-wait-for-no-man). However, in the mentioned duplicate, the OP is not interested in knowing which construct is correct. He's rather interested in knowing the nuance between *tide* and *time*. Hence, the answers provided there also talk about that nuance, rather than answering which construct is correct.

Comment: No, in this case those two words are synonyms. Because here *time* = *tide*, it takes a singular verb.

Comment: @tchrist: In the mentioned link, there is no resolution to my query. The OP is not interested in which construct is correct. He's interested rather in the subtlety between `tide` and `time`. Hence, the answers, in the mentioned link, do not provide a resolution to my question.

Comment: Why do you assume that one is incorrect? The answers there are the answers you need. When you use singular, it means one thing. Plural means two things. That's how English works. You only thought it was wrong because you failed to undestand that it was one thing not two.

Comment: Pardon me for saying this, but it just doesn't "sound" correct. Perhaps because I have heard the latter construct more often than the former.

Comment: It doesn't "sound" correct because you are thinking that it is talking about two different things when it's not. It's an ancient phrase from back when those two words meant the same thing. If you reanalyse the second to mean something different than the first, then it won't "sound" right. It all depends on how you think of it. Therefore it is not possible to say one is wrong and the other right.

Comment: @tchrist Hmmm, thanks. I think I'm getting it now. And yes, the mentioned question does throw good light on this issue. So, yes, it can be marked as duplicate.

Comment: You should be able to mark it as a duplicate yourself, right?

Comment: Yes. Done that.

Comment: The question is still opened. The older question *does* mention that "tide" is another word for "time" and hence the reason why *waits* was / is used. Your grammar book was correct after all, the author just failed to explain the meaning of the proverb.

Comment: I don't see that "time" and "tide" are conceptualised as a single unit. And virtually every attestation that I came across used plural "wait".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tide+waits+for+no%2C+tide+wait+for+no&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctide%20waits%20for%20no%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctide%20wait%20for%20no%3B%2Cc0), *wait* is around 10x more popular than *waits*, and has been since about 1850, and this doesn't subtract out the enormous number of *waits* instances which are actually illustrating the difference between the two versions (and the erroneousness of using *waits*).

[However](https://books.google.com/books?id=6NDYAAAAMAAJ&q=%22tide+waits+for+no%22&dq=%22tide+waits+for+no%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiguejjqKHNAhVCRFIKHSqpDFgQ6AEIHjAA), one of the earliest occurrences of the saying was in *The Disappointment or the Force of Credulity*, 1796, by Andrew Barton, and Barton rendered the saying as "Time and tide waits for no one."

Comment: I never knew about this **Ngram** thing. Thanks for this neat method/tool. I hope it will come handy in future.

Comment: If you take a look at the older question there is a reason why the *waits* in "time and tide waits for no one" is not erroneous. In the past, the two terms were synonymous, a case of reduplication. It's only nowadays that  we think of the two things as being separate.