# The time and place "is" or "are" listed in the invitation?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, compound-subjects, coordinating-conjunctions

Which is correct?

1. the time and place is listed in the invitation
2. the time and place are listed in the invitation

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332163/time-and-tide-waits-or-wait (but not of the question that that's marked as a duplicate of, which explores the words "tide" and "time", not the subject-verb agreement question).

Comment: I'm not sure that you can have a list if you consider 'time & place' to be a single idea. I think it has to be 'are' here.

Comment: Would you agree to the opinion that since time and place refer to a single event it is correct to use "the time and place is listed in the invitation"?

Answer (score -1):

The time and place are listed would be correct, as the “are” is referring to the plural subject(s) of time and place.

Comment: Thanks. I've also been told that it is correct to use "the time and place is listed on the invitation" because time and place are referring to a single event which is a singular subject.

Comment: Why anyone would downvote exjoburger's obvious Answer isn't evident, unless "time and place" have some special relationship that apples and pears and chalk and cheese don't share… which anyone's welcome to try to demonstrate.

Even the military, which does use "date-time groups" doesn't use "time-place" groups and I suggest we are not talking here about post-Einsteinian physics.

Sorry, Pat… two things are always plural.